# load view from another domain using jquery load by enabling CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to load view from another domain using jquery load function or by other way.
e.g. I have div in originaldomain.com and want to load view with full functionality like working actions (button click, sending api calls) which depends on jquery. That view is present on anotherdomain.com
I don't want to use iframe or object tag. I have enabled CORS in my anotherdomain.com project.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
        {
            if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin"))
            {
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Request.Headers.GetValues("Origin")[0]);
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

But it's not working. 
I am not getting any error. When I try to load the page using jquery load(url) control goes to Global.asax file but not hitting the controller's action. That's why I am not getting response of action to load inside div.

Comment: If the controller isn't getting hit then there must be something wrong with the url. Can you post the url you are using and the controller?

Comment: `$("#btnLoad").on("click", function () {
        $("#div2").load("http://localhost:55621/home/index", function (response, status, xhr) {
            console.log(response);//get empty response
            console.log(status);//get success
            console.log(xhr);
        });     
    });`
Url: http://localhost:55621/home/index
Controller Code:
`namespace Child.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {        
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}`
@aalcutt

Comment: @aalcutt Please review previous comment

Comment: Are you getting any CORS errors in the web browser?

Comment: No. I am not getting any CORS errors after adding mentioned code in Global.asax file. 
Traced in Network tab and got 200 success response but response text is empty. @aalcutt

Comment: Is the view empty? I can't really see anything that would be a problem with what you have shared so far

Comment: Please share me your mail id, I will share you source code. @aalcutt